# What does the phrase "digs of their dreams" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase **digs of their dreams** mean in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game Project Makeover:

> Give TV-show guests new looks and the **digs of their dreams** while
> solving match-3 puzzles.

I know the meanings of the idioms "dig in", "take a dig at" etc., but I have never seen the phrase "digs of".

Here is a description of the game from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgg.jump&hl=hi&gl=US):

> Give desperately needed makeovers to help people achieve their dreams!
> Choose highly fashionable clothes, hairstyles, makeup, and even
> furniture! Deal with dramatic characters like egotistical fashion
> icons, scheming assistants, or stubborn clients in dire need of a new
> wardrobe.

Comment: "digs" is slang for "home"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it's the (slightly old-fashioned) British use of *digs* to mean lodgings or living quarters. *The [noun] of their dreams* - the best they could possibly imagine.

Comment: Personally, I think the cited usage is an "affectation" from a writer who isn't *actually* familiar with how ***digs*** is (was?!)  used in BrE. As you say, it specifically means ***lodgings*** (not the more general "residence") - usually, the renting of a single room in a shared house *where the actual owner also lives*. Most such "lodgers, tenants, guests" probably wouldn't be *allowed* to give their room a substantial "makeover", even if they wanted to.

Comment: A lot of these 'curious' questions about game descriptions seem to be about text not written by a native speaker.

Comment: Digs often cater for a particular type of client - theatrical or student digs for example.

Answer (score 1):

“Digs” here means “residence,” whether apartment or house or trailer. It is slang.